# Python - pandas ExcelFile/read_excel - data import stops at first empty row

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Basically I read excel file

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(myFile)
sheetData = xl.parse('S1',header=1)
```

What happens is that only data in yellow is loaded. Import process is finished at first empty row. How to solve this?

[image]

Is it possible to configure parse/ExcelFile so that it would load whole data? For example checking last row in the sheet and going upwards.

Tried read_excel, however, results are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **add the argument to deal with `NA` cells**. You can do it using:

```
sheetData = xl.parse('S1',header=1, na_values=True)
```